# Kuiper's Test P Value in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value, circular-statistics

I am trying to implement a kuiper's test on a set of data and looking for an R package (or other program) **that can give a p-value without monte carlo simulation or only a range of p-values.** All of the packages (listed below) either give ranges of p-values or simulate (very limited because of time for simulation). I will be doing a large number of Kuiper's tests with small p-values.

The packages I've looked into:

- CircStats
- truncgof
- circular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to give a p-value without simulation or the use of critical values, we must be able to derive the null distribution of the test statistic.

For Kuiper's test, the null distribution of the test statistic is not known as far as I am aware. Because of this, we can not directly compute the p-value, and must either use critical values (which results in functions that return a range of p-values, as you note), or simulation (for example, bootstrapping), to obtain p-values.

Bootstrapping can be a straightforward way in this case to obtain a good approximation of the p-value.